# Call or access nested const inside variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

i'm newbie in javascript but i need help, can i access or call from outside a variable inside const block ? , from code in bottom, i need to access *layerAttributes* which the variable is inside addAttributes block, i try to console.log(layerAttributes); inside block is working, but i don't know how to call it from outside block, biggest appreciate for help and thank's in advance.

```
const addAttributes = (_element) => {
  let selectedElement = _element.layer;
  const layerAttributes = {
    trait_type: _element.layer.trait,
    value: selectedElement.traitValue,
    ...(_element.layer.display_type !== undefined && {
      display_type: _element.layer.display_type,
    }),
  };
  console.log(layerAttributes);
  if (
    attributesList.some(
      (attr) => attr.trait_type === layerAttributes.trait_type
    )   
  )
    return;
  attributesList.push(layerAttributes);
};
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you are returning a value...why not return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to be able to access layerAttributes from outside the block, you can declare it outside then use it inside the const block and outside like this:

```
let layerAttributes = {}; //declared outside the block
    
    const addAttributes = (_element) => {
      let selectedElement = _element.layer;
      layerAttributes = { //accessed inside the block
        trait_type: _element.layer.trait,
        value: selectedElement.traitValue,
        ...(_element.layer.display_type !== undefined && {
          display_type: _element.layer.display_type,
        }),
      };
      console.log(layerAttributes);
      if (
        attributesList.some(
          (attr) => attr.trait_type === layerAttributes.trait_type
        )   
      )
        return;
      attributesList.push(layerAttributes);
    
    }; //end of block

    console.log(layerAttributes); //accessed outside the block
```

tell me if this is what you meant

Comment: You can't do an assignment to a `const`. You could either make it a `let`, or use something like `Object.assign(layerAttributes, { trait_type: ... })` to add the properties without the assignment.

Comment: Yes true @David784

Comment: Thanks so much @YESSINE for the answer, apologize for incomplete question, what i need is accessing data inside layerAttributes, i need to access it from outside the block, your code is working like a charm, but when i call the layerAttributes data  from outside the block, no error and still no data return when i try with  console.log from outside the block.